# jQuery selector for text within element that isn't wrapped by an element?

Tags: jquery

Given this html:

```
<div id='tst1'>
  <div id='tst2'>tst2</div>
  <div id='tst3'>tst3</div>
  this is the text i want
</div>
```

How can I select for the 'this is the text i want' text?  `$('#tst1').text()` gives me all of the text elements contained within tst1 (e.g. tst2, tst3, etc.).

I cannot depend on knowing the id's of the contained wrapped elements (tst2, tst3 above), but I can depend on the text I want being listed last in the group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this plz:

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/We7mZ/ you can also look for `innerHTMl` and `outterHTML`

```
jQuery.fn.justtext = function() {

    return $(this).clone()
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text();

};
alert($('#tst1').justtext());​
```

Comment: @Tats_innit sometimes :), sleep is `undefined` :P

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe this if Tats suggestion doesn't work:

```
var text = $('#tst1').text();
text.substr(-23);
```

Comment: That's not the right syntax for `substr()`: should be `text.substr(-23)`, or for better cross-browser support `text.slice(-23)`, but even ignoring that I don't think the OP knows the length of the text in advance.

Comment: Haha, too much php lately;) Edited it...yeah if it is just not for that specific text it's really no good.

Comment: yes, i can't count on the specifics...just the general format